# After extending an access token, does that make it valid for another 60 days?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-access-token

If I requested and acquired an access token on, say, the 1st of March, and extended it on 30 days later, will it be valid for *another* 60 days, or does it require reauthorization from the end user?

We are implementing an autopost functionality, which is triggered by an event inside our own application. Therefore, the end user will not be able to present their cookie to Facebook in order to validate their identity. We need to make sure that we always have a valid access token.

The official Facebook documentation is quite vague on this particular subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you obtaining the access tokens? Server side flow or client side?
What exactly do you mean by "extending" the tokens? Are you referring to the "new end point" provided by facebook because of the [offline_access deprecation](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)?

You are right, facebook are pretty vague about it saying:

> If you would like to renew a still valid access_token, you will have
>   to get a new client-side access token first and then call the same
>   endpoint below. The returned access_token with the newly extended
>   expiration time may or may not be the same as the previously granted
>   extended access_token.

That means that you can not count on the extended token to actually be extended.
More than that though, is that you can't just extend the token with out any user interaction. If the user haven't used your app in the last 60 days you can not extend the token for him.

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding to my question! The access tokens are acquired by redirecting the user to the Facebook OAuth dialog, which will eventually redirect them back to a "handler page" on our server. By extending, I indeed mean using the new endpoint. So what you're saying is basically that it will only last for 60 days and then the user has to re-authorize the app? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not even sure that the new end point will work for you since you get the tokens from the server side and the new end point (according to the docs) work only for access tokens generated by a client side flow. Once the user authorized your app he won't need to re-authorize the app, the auth dialog will be skipped and the user will be redirected back to your app with a new shinny access token.

Comment: „So what you're saying is basically that it will only last for 60 days and then the user has to re-authorize the app?” – let’s put it that way, the user has to re-engage with your app within these 60 days, so that you can get a new access token (f.e. by calling the auth dialog, as Nitzan already said). If the user doesn’t visit your app again (or any page where you have a chance to call the auth dialog in some way), then you’ll have an expired access token after 60 days – and that’s the whole point of removing offline access, that apps can’t act on behalf of users „forever” any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `App Access Token` if you want to publish on users behalf. The `App Access Token` does not expire unless you **de-authorize** it yourself. When using your `App Access Token` you have to specifically indicate the **user id** you are publishing for - **/12345678/photos**. You can't use **/me/photos**. You can read more about this [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/).